# fbx mesh load geometry transformation

Tags: c++, directx, fbx

I am trying to load a car model from fbx file with one model that divided into 5 sub models.
4 sub models are the wheels and one sub model is the car.
At first when I tried to render it I Saw only one wheel so I start diagnostic on the frame.
I realized that all the four wheel are much more big then the car.
This and the fact that I see only one wheel make me think that in fbx each sub model has own transformation matrix.
Am I right?
And if yes how can I get the specific transformation for the specific sub model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All nodes in fbx have own transformation. You can take it by **EvaluateLocalTransform**(if you keep hierarchy) or **EvaluateGlobalTransform** (if you don't)

Comment: Can I get translation rotation and scale separately in global (without hierarchy)?

Comment: As I said, use **EvaluateGlobalTransform** if don't keep hierarchy.

Comment: Yes I got it. But what should I use if I want to get only the rotation for example?

Comment: You will get matrix 4x4, which contains all components - translation, rotation and scale. Then you can use matrix decomposition. It will decompose matrix to this parts.

Comment: Oh, fbx matrix already have all functions. Check [link](http://docs.autodesk.com/FBX/2014/ENU/FBX-SDK-Documentation/cpp_ref/class_fbx_a_matrix.html)